# showing white screen when navigate to next page iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova

When I try to move to the next page using `window.open` on my iPhone, I always get a
quick white screen before the next page is loaded. I am using jquery mobile and cordova 2.1.

I have two pages.. I used the code below to move to the next page when I click on the "next" button :

```
function MovetoNextForm()
{
    window.open("nextpage.html");   
}
```

It moves to the next page, but the problem is before the next page appears, it's showing a white screen for few seconds (1-2 sec).

I have used these includes :

```
<script src="cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here are some screenshots of the issue.

Firstpage :

[image: First page]

White screen :

[image: White screen]

Secondpage :

[image: Second page]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: How to avoid this issue like showing white screen while navigating to next page?

Answer (score 3):

You should use $.mobile.changePage("pagename.html").

Also you should read http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html for more information about Multi-Pages templates in jQuery Mobile.

Kind regards,

Comment: thank you for your response...the changepage method used to change only the content of the page. in our phonegap application we need to load the whole page(script,DOM,and onDeviceReady methods).. these things not getting fire when i use changepage method.. this is working with window.open method

Comment: You could use the window.open method, but this indeed reloads the whole DOM. 
As jQM implements not needing to reload the full DOM you'll take advantage of this feature.